# sending Json array failed

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, scriptmanager

I am building a JSON/WCF app and need to send an array of objects back to the server. For some reason it is not accepting the array. Using script manager I can get data fine.

```
  var month = $("#ddlStartMonth").val();
            var year = $("#ddlStartYear").val();
            var items = JSON.stringify(calendarItems);
            WebService.SaveCalendar(items, new Date(year, month, 01).toDateString(), new Date(year, month, 01).toDateString(), Submit, onPageError);
```

I have tried with and without the JSON stringify. The function onPageError is activated and the only error info it produces is "The server method 'SaveCalendar' failed". Yet the breakpoint on the first line of the web method is not activated.

```
    <OperationContract()>
<WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
    Public Function SaveCalendar(ByVal _jsonImages As String()(), ByVal _selectedMonth As String, ByVal _selectedYear As String) As Boolean
        Dim _calenderItems As New List(Of CalenderItem)
        '_calenderItems = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of CalenderItem))(_jsonImages)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("calenderItems") = _calenderItems
        HttpContext.Current.Session("selectedMonth") = New Date(_selectedMonth)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("selectedYear") = New Date(_selectedYear)
        Return True
    End Function
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: btw the status code returned by the wcf service is 400

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues working with MVC. I think .NET's deserializer actually expects that the object it is passed will be a JSON *object* rather than an *array* (i.e. it should always start with "{" and end with "}". You could:

1. Create a POCO class to act as your DTO which simply has a List/Array of CalenderItems inside of it, or
2. Use a more "lenient" deserializer like Newtonsoft's JSON.NET

Of course this second option would only work if you can somehow convince WCF to run the method in the first place.  Looking at your code again, though, I'm wondering if your declaring _jsonImages as a double-array of strings might be causing some difficulty.

Comment: +1 because JSON.NET has helped me solve issues like this before.

Comment: I first tried declaring _jsonImages as a non-array string. Neither of these solutions work, I also tried adding "{" and end with "} and it had no effect.

Comment: I add try sending one object instead of an array of objects and it works.